# The package at "functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\logger\index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util"

Tags: react-native, expo, sendgrid

I have wasted 3-4 to send form data with image from react native expo app using firebase cloud functions and sendGrid I have tried nodemailer also but doesn't workout. I am getting error while deploying function. I have send email logic as given below and I have triggered sendEmailFunction in my form component and passed autoId as parameter , please help me how to solve this issue please.

[image]

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in
> the user code. Error message: Provided module can't be loaded. Is
> there a syntax error in your code? Detailed stack trace:
> /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:174
> this.appStore?.removeApp(this.name);
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at Object. (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/lifecycle.js:25:24)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10) Could not load the function,
> shutting down.. Please visit
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth
> troubleshooting documentation.
>
> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
> sendEmailFunction(us-central1) i  functions: cleaning up build files...
>
> Error: There was an error deploying functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

// Initialize SendGrid with your API key
sgMail.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid.key);

exports.sendEmailFunction = functions.firestore
  .document("formData/entry/signalements/{autoId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    const data = snap.data();
    // Convert the data object into a HTML table
    let html = "<table><tr><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
    for (const key in data) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(data, key)) {
        html += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${data[key]}</td></tr>`;
      }
    }
    html += "</table>";
    const msg = {
      to: "toexample@gmail.com",
      from: "fromexample@gmail.com",
      subject: "New Form Submission",
      // Use the html property instead of text
      html: html,
    };
    try {
      await sgMail.send(msg);
      console.log("Email sent");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });


const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const isValid = validateForm(
    formValues,
    formName,
    setFieldErrors,
    showTextField
  );

  // Check if the select input is invalid
  const isSelectInvalid =
    formValues.selectedValue === null ||
    formValues.selectedValue === "Choisir la catégorie";

  if (isSelectInvalid) {
    setIsSelectInvalid(true);
  }
  if (isValid) {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      // Upload the image to Firebase Cloud Storage
      const uri = formValues.pickedImage[0].uri;
      const imageRef = await uploadImage(uri, formName);

      // Get the download URL of the uploaded image
      const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);

      // Create a new object with the form data and the image download URL
      const formDataWithImage = {
        ...formValues,
        pickedImage: downloadUrl,
      };

      await handleFormSubmit(formDataWithImage, setFieldErrors);

      // Reset form data if needed
      setFormValues({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        email: "",
        message: "",
        address: "",
        specify: "",
        selectedValue: null,
        pickedImage: null,
      });
      await sendEmailFunction(autoId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading image or storing form data:", error);
      // Handle error
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setFieldErrors({});
      setFormValues(false);
    }
  }
};
```